# Multivariable Limit for Some Function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to compute the following limit and am trying to determine a way to compute

$$f(\mu _1,\mu _2,\mu _3,\mu_4)=\frac{\lambda  \mu _2 \mu _3}{\left(\mu _2-\mu _1\right) \left(\lambda ^3+\mu _3 \left(2 \lambda ^2+\mu _2 \left(2 \lambda +\mu _1\right)\right)\right)}.$$

The equation "blows up" when $(\mu _1,\mu _2,\mu _3,\mu_4)\rightarrow (1 ,1,1,1)$.

$$\lim_{(\mu _1,\mu _2,\mu _3,\mu_4)\rightarrow (1 ,1,1,1)} f(\mu _1,\mu _2,\mu _3,\mu_4)$$

I tried using L'Hopital's rule, but the problem is that it does not apply to multivariable calculus.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a $4$-tuple to converge to $1.$

Comment: Ok - I am unclear of the notation I should use, but each of $\mu_i$ approaches 1

Comment: What is $\lambda?$

Comment: It's just a constant > 0 and a real number

Comment: If $\lambda>0$, then the only problem at $(1,1,1,1)$ is with $(\mu_2-\mu_1)$ in the denominator. So the limit can’t exist (even as an infinite limit) since it would be $\pm\infty$ depending on the sign of that difference during approach. And, worse, if $\mu_2=0$ or $\mu_3=0$ during approach, the limit could be $0$.

Comment: Ok - I see now - Thanks - Bummer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(\mu _1,\mu _2,\mu _3,\mu_4)=\frac{\lambda  \mu _2 \mu _3}{\left(\mu _2-\mu _1\right) \left(\lambda ^3+\mu _3 \left(2 \lambda ^2+\mu _2 \left(2 \lambda +\mu _1\right)\right)\right)}$$ When the $\mu_i \to 1$, this reduces to
$$\frac {\lambda}{\left(\mu _2-\mu _1\right)(\lambda +1) \left(\lambda ^2+\lambda +1\right) }$$ and then $\cdots$